# WPF blurry texts: Where/How to set TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, rendering

I am rendering text but the output of small font sizes is quite bad. This seems to be an old wpf rendering issue. But there should be solutions available, see [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions).

As far as I understand it comes down to setting the  TextOptions.TextRenderingMode to TextRenderingMode.Aliased in order to get sharper output.
I tried doing that, but the result did not change.

My question is, on which dependency object do I need to set the renderoption?
I am doing it like this:

```
  var text = new FormattedText(...);
  var textGeometry = text.BuildGeometry(position);
  var drawing = new GeometryDrawing(brush, null, textGeometry);
  TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(drawing, TextFormattingMode.Display);
  TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(drawing, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);
  theDrawing.Children.Add(drawing);
```

Later I am using a RenderTargetBitmap in order to render the drawings.
That bitmap has also set all renderoptions like posted above. Finally this bitmap gets displayed within a Imagecontrol (all UI elements have Textoptions + Renderoptions set as well) But no success...
Maybe my problem is that I am using a GeometryDrawing and thus my text does not get recognized as text...

Thanx for all your input!

Edit:

UI Code:

```
  TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
  TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this.ImageControl, TextFormattingMode.Display);

  TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(this, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);
  TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(this.ImageControl, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);
```

Comment: Because you are painting the text you are losing any ability to re-render the text the problem is likely to be because the final image is being scaled

Comment: By painting you mean the step when the bitmap renders the drawing -
 correct?

Comment: Yes you will always get lower quality text when you embed it in an image as it stops being text and becomes a picture subject to stretching, shrinking and lossy encoders

Comment: Ok, but how could i avoid that renderstep if i want to use it as a Image.Source on the UI?  Is there a different way of handing the (not rendered) drawings to the UI?

Comment: i would suggest storing the text as meta data and then placing it in controls over the image, the only time you should need to manually render a UI is if your saving screenshots

Comment: Thanx for your input MikeT! Guess i have to overthink our concept. One goal was to have the possibility to use the wpf render output bitmap in other environments if needed. Thats the reason why i rendered a bitmap manually.  Anyway, your postings pointed me in the right direction...

Comment: A closing note: Indeed the blurriness was a result of a bitmap scaling. I implemented a solution that uses drawingVisuals as childs of a Visualhost UI element (thus renounce the bitmap rendering) -> voila`, all fonts are sharp!

Comment: As stated, the scaling of the bitmap was leading to blurry fonts. 
I looked closer into that, as i thought my Imagecontrol and my bitmap had exactly the same size. 
But, as i learned, that was not the case. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045697/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-image-control-to-have-same-dimensions-as-its-bitmapimage-s
Setting Stretch to "none" on the Imagecontrol can do the trick...